# Always shows "Local calendar cannot sync with Google calendar. You need a google account."

Tags: sync, calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-2, system-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Local calendar cannot sync with Google calendar…” bur it can? What?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13693/local-calendar-cannot-sync-with-google-calendar-bur-it-can-what)

It says this every time I try to make a new event on my new Bell Samsung Galaxy S II, then gives me an option to "Go to account and sync," so I do. I click on my specific account then click "Sync now." Contacts and Gmail complete and the sync circles disappear, but Calendar's stops spinning very quickly, then doesn't move, then disappears a bit later. I go back in to make a new event and the same error appears.

I made a test event, and it appears online when I check from my laptop, but the message still appears every time I make a new event.

Comment: New version of this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13693/local-calendar-cannot-sync-with-google-calendar-bur-it-can-what