# how to take a backup of my calender events in galaxy ace duos

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calendar, samsung-galaxy-ace

is there any way to take a backup of my calender events in galaxy ace duos.
am searching for the third party software but couldn't find one.

Comment: Does [How to backup the Android calendar file (is there such a file)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25210/16575) (see also the other questions linked/related there) cover your issue? Several more solutions might be found in [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=15) (to sync your calendar with other sources) or [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=32#group_135) (backup/restore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your calendar using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.aichbauer.ical&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

- One way is to sync up your calendar with your Google Account: Go to `Settings > Select "Google" under Accounts > Click on your Google Account` and now select `Calendar`.
- Check if the discussion under [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25210/how-to-backup-the-android-calendar-file-is-there-such-a-file) question helps.

Comment: Whether it will add the local calender events to google account calender?