# How to extract calendar data from the stock calendar app of Android Gingerbread (2.3.6) without a Google account?

Tags: backup, 2.3-gingerbread, calendar, offline

I am confronted with an old Android phone:

- OS: Gingerbread (2.3.6)
- Type: Motorola XT320

It holds quite a significant amount of **data in its local calendar**, operated by what appears to be the **stock calendar app of Android** of that era. The phone is not (and has never been) connected to a Google account.

**How can I extract this data onto a computer** (preferably without having to create a Google account etc. since this particular data actually is not Google's business)**?**

---

I have looked at the following questions, among others:

- [How can data on an unrooted phone be backed up?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12470)
- [How to backup the Android calendar file (is there such a file)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25210)
- [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296)

I am aware of this [iCal Import/Export CalDAV app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.drlue.icalimportexport&hl=de) which appears to be only available in Google's Playstore - as far as I can tell a no-go without a Google account.

I have experimented with the [Calendar Import-Export app](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/org.sufficientlysecure.ical/) from F-Droid. The good news is that it is available (and still maintained) for Gingerbread. The bad news is that it does not see my calendar. This appears to be a dead-end so far. EDIT: I just filed [a bug report](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/calendar-import-export/issues/72) against it.

I am no stranger to ADB - the phone has developer options enabled. From my research and test runs, I learned that `adb backup` only became available with Android 4, so this is no option for me. By gaining access to a shell on the phone (`adb shell`) I furthermore learned that the folder `/data` (where according to Android's documentation the calendar data should be located) can not be accessed by a regular user. My understanding is that `/data` is located on the phone's internal memory (not on its SD card) where it is protected by Android's security model.

In the context of ADB, I came across this [project on Github](https://github.com/sromku/adb-export). I am not entirely sure whether or not this will work with Gingerbread. The one thing I know is that I probably need to root my phone first before I can find out. Right now, targeting `content://com.android.calendar/calendars`, the script exits with `Querying DB: Done` and `content: permission denied0%`.

My four options left, as far as I can tell, are:

- Going through the hassle of creating a Google account and extracting my data through Google cloud (and I **really** do not want to go down this path).
- Rooting my phone so I can access whatever is stored in `/data` in the hopes that I can convert it to something readable (e.g. an `ical` file). If I understand the documentation correctly, the stock Android calendar app stores its data in a SQLite database file. I have yet not found a definition of how this data is stored in the database (which I could use to write some code to convert it). Funny side note: [I have NOT yet found a "safe" way of rooting this particular type of phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203306/278060). The general advise given: Backup **all** your data before trying ...
- Android 2 allows to connect the phone to a Microsoft Exchange service (in addition to or even instead of a Google account). Theoretically, this should allow me to set up my own Exchange service in one way or the other and to get the data out this way ...
- Going through the calendar by hand and writing every event into a computer manually as well. Given the amount of time I have spent researching this, it does not appear to be the worst option ...

I'd love to hear if there are any other options left that I might have overlooked or misinterpreted ... I am pretty damn frustrated at this point.

Comment: Is the device rooted? Then you could extract the corresponding database.

Comment: @Izzy It is not (yet). As stated above, I also have not found a "relatively safe" way to do it for this particular type of phone without risking to loose the relevant data.

Comment: @Izzy I just posted a [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203306/278060) about how to root this phone.

Comment: OK, when you achieved that, you can copy the database of the "calendar provider" (`com.android.providers.calendar`) to your SD card and pull it from there.

Comment: @Izzy Is not the "calendar provider" in this form an Android >= 4 thing?

Comment: My last pre-ICS experiences are some time ago – but AFAIR it was that way even back with Eclair (Android 2.1 – the first one I actually dug into), and definitely was there with Froyo (2.2, where I long time kept a copy of `/data` on my computer to investigate). Check below `/data/data`, and you most likely will find it.