# How to "safely" root a Motorola XT320 (running Android 2.3.6 / Gingerbread) without loosing data?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 2.3-gingerbread, motorola

Related to this question: [How to extract calendar data from the stock calendar app of Android Gingerbread (2.3.6) without a Google account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203280/278060)

How can I "safely" root a Motorola XT320 phone running Android 2.3.6 / Gingerbread? It is my intent to do this without loosing any data. Through root privileges, I hope to gain access to certain data on the phone (a local calendar) which I want to backup.

I have to admit I am new to this field. As far as I can tell, the most recommended app for this purpose appears to be [KINGO ROOT](https://www.kingoapp.com/android-root/devices.htm). Unfortunately, my phone is not on the compatibility list. If I understand the matter correctly, this rules out a relatively "safe", mostly non-invasive exploit-based root approach and only leaves flashing certain parts of the ROM as an option. The latter should only be done **after** a backup of all essential data has been made ...

Because this phone and its OS are rather old, I was wondering whether anybody around here has any (past) experience that could help me.

Comment: have u seen this page maybe it can help https://www.oneclickroot.com/root/motorola-xt320-tnbst_4_07-23-15rps-2-3-6/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. But you need to be cautious and do a little bit research before choosing one.

Step 1. Back up all your data to pc or sd card (if sd card then better remove it after backup is complete). For pc you can use tools like moboginey pc suit.

Next you can use one click root functionality of mobogine. Or try following guidelines here - https://www.oneclickroot.com/root/motorola-xt320-tnbst_4_07-23-15rps-2-3-6/

Comment: https://motorola-global-en-roe.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/77416/p/30,6720,8421

Comment: Thanks. The stock calendar app in **Gingerbread** AFAIK does not allow to sync a (previously) local calendar to a service other than Google could.  Because I want to avoid Google cloud, syncing the data out to a calendar server of my own is unfortunately not an option.  `Step 1. Back up all your data` - yeah, I have seen this advice before. Hence my quest for a **relatively safe** option. **I can not backup the relevant data without rooting the device first** :( The `you need to be cautious` part is where I am seeking advice from people who have experience with this or similar types of phones.

Comment: Did you try using moboginey?

Comment: "Fake google account" / "outlook calendar": If you can provide a working example / set of instructions, feel free to post it as an [answer to the related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203280/278060) :)

Comment: 1. Create a new google account, 2. Add it to your phone, 3. sync calendar -- now data is synced with your new google account. 4. export calendar as csv from google calendar.

Comment: hope this helps. please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111?hl=en

Comment: `[...] google account, 2. Add it to your phone, 3. sync calendar` ... this really does NOT avoid Google cloud, I am afraid. This is precisely what I do not want to do (with just any Google account). When I saw the phrase `fake google account` I sort of expected a way avoiding to involve Google's servers / infrastructure :/ Sry, but this does not help.

Comment: Why you dont want to involve google?