# How do you sync from one calendar account to another?

Tags: sync, lineageos, calendar, google-calendar, caldav

I am trying to migrate from a broken calendar account (no remote sync access, but the phone has all the data cached locally) to a [self-hosted CalDAV calendar](https://radicale.org/v3.html) (connected to by [DAVx](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/at.bitfire.davdroid/)).  Both calendar accounts are in DAVx, and both are visible in calendar apps.

Question: How do you export an existing calendar to another calendar on the device?  I have both the "Google Calendar" app and the default Calendar app that comes with LineageOS, but neither appear to support export/import---or at least I cannot find the option.  There are *lots* of calendar events, so we need to do it in bulk.

With contacts, it is simple: you can export a .vcs to a file and import the .vcs to another contact account with the "Contacts" app.  But with I can't figure out how to do the same thing with a calendar account.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a well-supported and up-to-date solution on F-Droid:

- https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.sufficientlysecure.ical/

and this is the project on GitHub:

- https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/calendar-import-export

See also this related question:

- [How to backup the Android calendar file (is there such a file)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25210/how-to-backup-the-android-calendar-file-is-there-such-a-file/255437)